# Is it save to overrwrite the savedInstanceState bundle after passing it up?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have the following (to avoid checking if a fragment is being created newly or just being recreated)

```
@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle args) {
  super.onActivityCreated(args);
  if (this.getArguments() != null) args = this.getArguments();
 // rest of fragment loading goes here
}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to make a local field in fragment and access it by calling getArguments();

You can try it with static factory method that puts a argument to fragment from outside of class. Like getFragment from  ViewPagerFragment adapter.

Comment: "Is it save" with regards to what? You're not overwriting anything, except your local reference `args`. You're not changing the `Bundle` passed up through the `super` call.

Comment: `Java` is `pass-by-value`, so yes, it is safe, you just changing local `args` variable to point to another object

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do never seen budle values being overwritten.

If you want some values to be availbale inside fragment pass those values to activity and inside fragment call getActivity().getIntent().getExtra(

Otherwise have a look at code below if want save some fragment data if fragment is destroyed
Inside fragment in onCreate method check if savedInstanceState is null or not

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //fragment recreated
    }
  }
```

Save data as follows

```
     @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

   if (jsonObject != null) {
        outState.putString(Constants.JSON, jsonObject.toString());
   }

}
```

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: If savedinstance is not null fragment is recreated as simple as that

Comment: I thought he is asking how to reload data when fragment is recreated thats why above code